# Best Way to Implement Window + Multiline Text in Android

Tags: android

I'm really new to Android development. I have no idea what search keyword should I use for this.

[image]

Is it possible to create something like this in Android?
What component should I use for the window and also the text?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have and html page for this terms & conditions or simply text details ?

Answer (score 0):

You could re-style an [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) for the window (see the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)). Text is normally shown in a [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

For setting the TextView to multi-line, there is the [`android:inputType`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).